# passing array from model to controller and only using it within the controller

Tags: php, arrays, session, codeigniter-2

i'm traying to build a login system with session on my own as practise and i've run into a problem that i can't seem to solve.

when a user logs into my test website i want to get some of his data from database(like surname and email) and put it into his session.
before this i used the return true or false method and added a costum entry into the session but now i want to add extra things that i can easly access on other pages like username/email etc.

i've tried diff methods of passing the data from model to controller but i can't seem to find a way to use the array of info inside the controller itself.

my current code looks like this:

this is the MODEL

```
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[]['id'] = $row->id;
                $data[]['name'] = $row->name;
                $data[]['surname'] = $row->surname;
                $data[]['username'] = $row->username;
                $data[]['email'] = $row->email;
                $data[]['premission_level'] = $row->premission_level;
                $data[]['disabled'] = $row->disabled;
            }
        }
        return $data;
}
```

after it gets the data it goes to this controller:

```
    public function clogin()
{
    $this->load->model('M_login');
    $query = $this->M_login->mlogin();

    if($query == TRUE)
    {
        $data['product'] = $this->M_login->get_user_info();
        $session_data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => TRUE
                    );
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
           echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
    }

}
```

after this i'm lost as how to get the info from the array.
the array gets passed down succesfully becouse i can use the print_r to see what's inside.

PS: the current fields inside the array are username/name/surname/email/disabled.

thank you in advance.

EDIT: this is how my array looks like:

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array

```
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => war
        [surname] => howl
        [username] => warhowl
        [email] => someone@none.com
        [premission_level] => 1
        [disabled] => 0
    )
```

)

Comment: Please, post the print_r and tell which info you want to access.

Comment: i edited my question and added the array, seems i can't add codes in comments. the ones i want to access right now are name/surname and email. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting your row's fields into separated arrays with:

```
$data[]['id'] = $row->id;
$data[]['name'] = $row->name;
...
```

Try with:

```
$rowData = array();
$rowData['id'] = $row->id;
$rowData['name'] = $row->name;

$data[] = $rowData
```

Or just

```
$data[] = array(
    'id'   => $row->id,
    'name' => $row->name,
    ...
);
```

Comment: i had a fresh look today and it seems i was not supplying the right index and so i kept getting error in retrieving the data from the array. thank you all for you help. i'll leave it open for another few hours in case i still run into some trouble.